Doubt regarding Ehull (energy above convex hull) and formation energy
I am creating a ML model for predicting thermodynamic-stability of 2-d materials, for predicting stability formation energy and Ehull (Energy above convex hull) is used and this is how it is also present in C2DB database also, but in 2dmatpedia for energy ,this is given for each element.
"energy": -3.41639962,
"energy_per_atom": -3.41639962,
"energy_vdw": -2.81688813,
"energy_vdw_per_atom": -2.81688813

Is any out of these 4 same as formation energy or Ehull??

+1. Welcome to our community.

None of these are $E_{hull}$. These are absolute electronic energies, the hill is stability relative to other phases.
